# Excelのセルの値を呼び出したい

Tags: python

タイトル通りなのですが、sheetのところでエラーになってしまいます。

ご教授いただけましたら幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

```py
import xlrd
file_location = "/Users/names/Book2.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0)
sheet.nrows
shoot.ncols
for col in range(sheet.ncols):
    print sheet.cell_value(0,col)
```

```
File "/Users/names/Desktop/\u6cb3\u91ce\u662d\u543e/excel5.py", line 9
    print sheet.cell_value(0,col)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.072s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

カッコをつけて `print(sheet.cell_value(0, col))` としてください。

Python 2 と 3 で `print` の構文が変わっています。Python 2 ではカッコをつけないのが通常でしたが、Python 3 ではカッコをつけるようになっています。古いコードに良くある違いです。

Python 2 と 3 の良くある違いについては、たとえば[こちらのページ](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html)のコード例が分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: nekketsuu様。ご回答いただきありがとうございます。実行できました、誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。もしよければ[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)して頂けると幸いです :)

Comment: nekketsu様。承認いたしました、今後とも何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。